# Input argument "c" is undefined, How to pass c to foo2() ? [matlab]

Tags: matlab, oop

I have the following code:

```
classdef ClassA

properties
    A;
    B;

end

methods
function obj = ClassA(A,B)

    obj.A = 1;
    obj.B = 2;
    obj.foo1();

end
 function c = foo1(obj,A,B)

    c = obj.A+obj.B;
    obj.foo2()

 end
 function foo2(obj,c,A)
     disp(c);
     disp(obj.A);

 end

end
end
```

I am trying to get the value of variable c from foo1(obj,A,B), and pass to foo2(obj,c,A), when I do so, I get the following error:

```
Input argument "c" is undefined.
```

I tried to solve it by write foo2 in this way:

```
foo2(c,A)
```

then I got this:

```
Undefined variable "obj" or class "obj.A"
```

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as an input

```
obj.foo2( c )
```